# SQL Server datetime rounding

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) "Rounding of datetime Fractional Second Precision" it should truncate the following Date when saving into a `datetime` column:

```
new DateTime(635180453197748530L)  //22 October 2013 13:28:39.7748530
// write to SQL server and re-read it
// result should be = 6351804531977 3 0000L
```

However, it is reproducible `6351804531977 7 0000L`. Is this a bug or do I have any problems in my understanding of the algorithm?

(we use Entity Framework for read/write to DB)

Comment: I suspect something in ADO.Net is rounding it to a complete number of milliseconds, but then the rounding on the page you're referencing kicks in (so you're getting double rounding) and it ends up rounding up the 5 to 7.

Comment: Sounds like a good hint, I'll do some checks!

Comment: I spent a long time spelunking through .NET code in `System.Data` today and I couldn't find the problem - but it's still my suspicion that it's a double rounding problem.

Comment: do you experience the same issue if you pass lower precision date? have you tried to change column in DB to `DATETIME2` it comes with `0 to 7 digits, with an accuracy of 100ns. The default precision is 7 digits.`

Comment: Are you using DateTime or DateTime2 in SQL Server?

Comment: Could the cause be that sql server doesn't actually have single millisecond precision? A single "tick" in a sql server datetime column is about 3 milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes before I write a datetime to the database, I cast it to SqlDateTime, which I have found produces much more predictable results with regards to rounding/truncation than simply writing the CLR datatype to the database directly.